# Changing programmatically connection properties after failed connection attempt - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection

I want to change connection properties programmaticaly if hibernate cant connect to database. I am trying to do this using this code:

```
    String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + Cfg.getHost() + ":" + Cfg.getPort() + ":" + Cfg.getSid();

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()            
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", connectionString)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", Cfg.getPassword())
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", Cfg.getLogin());

    sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Properties are from property file. But buildSessionFactory work for the first connection attempt. For anothers attempts he ignoring configuarion and doesnt want to create new SessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

SessionFactory is supposed to be created once. Later on during runtime, you should create sessions for your DB operations using that factory.

Comment: how can I connect to the database if I dont properly connect to the database for the first time?

Comment: I want change database, open session for database where i cant connect dont help me.